# Explode string to array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string

I wanted to explode the string in this kind of out

given the string value 
`$string = "Hello World Hey;`

explode function will be the immediate call if you wanted to have an output of array of string  `["Hello","World","Hey"]`

However this is the kind of output i want to achieved `["Hello","World","Hey","Hello World","World Hey"]`

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Explode the string into words then loop through and create unique combinations of the words.

Comment: Do u have a solution that i can look on?

Comment: this follow when string is more than 3 words.

Comment: why not `World Hey` also as an output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What's the rule behind splitting it that way?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str = "Hello World Hey";
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$res_arr = $arr;

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    if($i > 0)
    {
        $res_arr[] = $arr[$i - 1]." ".$arr[$i];
    }
}

print_r($res_arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => World
    [2] => Hey
    [3] => Hello World
    [4] => World Hey
)
```

Comment: Look good, you can improve this by setting the `$i` start at 1, then you can remove the condition.

Comment: @catcon but then I would still need an if case for the last iteration (undefined offset)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get the individual parts as well as the overlapping matching for the current and the next word, an alternative solution could be to use an expression.

You could capture the overlapping matches in a group using a positive lookahead and also capture the single "words" by matching 1+ times a non whitepace character and using a branch reset group `(?|`

```
$string = "Hello World Hey";
$res = preg_match_all("/(?|(?:^|\h)(?=(\S+ \S+))|(\S+))/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello World
    [1] => Hello
    [2] => World Hey
    [3] => World
    [4] => Hey
)
```

[Pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/8c8mi7/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/rdLdk)

If you would like the current and the 2 following words, you could use a group and a quantifier `{2}`

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/sRfee)

Answer (score 0):

```
function str_arr($str) {

    $arr = explode(' ', $str);

    $len = count($arr);
    for($i=0; $i<$len-1; $i++)
        $arr[] = $arr[$i] . ' ' . $arr[$i+1];

    return $arr;
}
```

for input "Hello World Hey" above function returns this array

```
["Hello","World","Hey","Hello World","World Hey"]
```